# How to persist an EnumMap in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently trying to persist data which I'd stored as a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) in Java.
I've gotten this to work using [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) already, however when I try to make this a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) instead using [`@MapKeyEnumerated`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyEnumerated.html) and `@MapKey` it acts a bit unexpected.

**ExampleData.java**

```java
@MapKey(name = "feature")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@OneToMany(targetEntity = ExampleFeature.class, mappedBy = "exampleData")
private Map<Feature, ExampleFeature> features;
```

**ExampleFeature.java**

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "example_id", nullable = false)
private ExampleData exampleData;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "feature", nullable = false)
private Feature feature;
```

I'm able to add rows to the database manually outside of runtime, and when running the application it's able to load those entities correctly. All other entities are also working as intended.

When persisting entities in from the application, the `ExampleFeature` does appear in the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), but all properties in the instance are the default Java values, and after stepping-out

#### Dependencies

- [`org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.17.Final`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.17.Final?smo=true)
- [`org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.4.17.Final`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/5.4.17.Final?smo=true)

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what I might have wrong here?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK I've included the modules I'm depending on, and the version in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the project, `#save()` was only called on `ExampleData`, but not on any of the relational properties under it. This means that Hibernate would try to persist the `ExampleData` instance, however not any nested properties such as the [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html).

The solution is to set `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` which will tell Hibernate to persist changes in relational entities such as `ExampleFeature` when persisting `ExampleData`.

**ExampleData.java**

```java
@MapKey(name = "feature")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@OneToMany(targetEntity = ExampleFeature.class, mappedBy = "exampleData", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Map<Feature, ExampleFeature> features;
```